# Is it possible to travel around the world using JUST Low-cost carriers?

Tags: air-travel, budget, international-travel, low-cost-carriers

Is it possible to visit all six non-Antarctica continents, just flying, using only Low Cost Carriers?

Comment: How do you define "low-cost carriers" here? By a specific price point, or a specific service level, or...?

Comment: @Flimzy Not offering proper connections would be the main defining characteristic, I think. But it's true the definitions have become blurred and many typical practices (e.g. no food, no free hold luggage, etc.) have been adopted by legacy airlines on some flights.

Comment: Do you count places that are considered in 2 continents once; such as Panama, Suez, and Istanbul?

Comment: @bunyaCloven doesn't matter how many times in each continent, as long as you can keep going and get around to the next one.

Comment: I meant that you could just go to Istanbul once, cross the bosphorus twice, and you would have been in Asia and Europe technically.

Comment: That's sneaky, I like it! :D

Comment: @bunyaCloven As far as I'm aware most people consider the boundary of South America to be in the Darien Gap, which is [notoriously difficult to cross](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93/suitable-ways-to-get-around-the-dari%c3%a9n-gap).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out, it is now possible, thanks to a post I found on [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Low-cost_airlines).

A sample itinerary, that they provide, beginning in **London**:

> **London** to Barcelona on Vueling
>   Barcelona to Casablanca on Vueling
>   Casablanca to Istanbul on Air Arabia Maroc
>   Istanbul to Dubai on Flydubai
>   Dubai to Kathmandu on Flydubai
>   Kathmandu to Kuala Lumpur on Air Asia X
>   Kuala Lumpur to Melbourne on Air Asia X
>   Melbourne to Honolulu on Jetstar
>   Honolulu to Vancouver on Westjet
>   Vancouver to Cancun on Westjet
>   Cancun to Mexico City on Interjet
>   Mexico City to Bogota on Interjet
>   Bogota to Fort Lauderdale on Spirit Airways
>   Fort Lauderdale to Oslo on Norwegian Air Shuttle
>   Oslo to **London** on Norwegian Air Shuttle

Of course there are complications in doing so, as RTW tickets tend to imply a long trip, and LCCs often re-do their routes and cancel/change itineraries.

Comment: @pnuts with who??

Comment: Norwegian now also serve the US direct from Gatwick, so you could combine the last two legs if you wanted

Answer (score 6):

Recently, a Dutch guy reached it to the [national newspapers](https://translate.google.nl/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ad.nl%2Fad%2Fnl%2F1100%2FConsument%2Farticle%2Fdetail%2F3544583%2F2013%2F11%2F14%2FGestoorde-hobby-brengt-student-Valentijn-overal.dhtml&edit-text=&act=url), with is hobby of searching low cost flight tickets.

Apparently, he manages to get a lot of discounts, and collect frequent flyer passes with many airliners. For example:

> I found a ticket from Paris for only 7 euros 50 It was a mistake of the airline, but I was going for a song in Asia.

He used this approach not only for this trip, but for trips all around the world, and to all continents.

Downside of his approach: he spends a lot of time looking for flights, and needs many transits on his travel. Furthermore, he books most flights more than a year in advance. However, it is fairly cheap for him (considering he is a student).

Comment: @pnuts Realized that after I typed the answer, but I think it might be interesting for future readers.