# Are there low-cost airlines operating from Europe to Dominican Republic?

Tags: low-cost-carriers, dominican-republic

Are there any low-cost airlines operating from Europe to Dominican Republic?

Comment: I think your only low cost option for crossing the atlantic right now is Norwegian Air Shuttle - see [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35892/is-it-possible-to-travel-around-the-world-using-just-low-cost-carriers) which has some overlap

Comment: [Ryanair](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/10665050/Ryanairs-10-flights-to-the-US-would-the-experience-be-worth-the-savings.html) might do that as well...

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Ryanair talks about a lot of things that they have no intention of actually doing.

Comment: @nate hence the "might" ;)

Comment: *Europe* sounds too broad to me. You can fly from anywhere in Europe?

Answer (score 2):

[Wamos Air (formerly Pullmantur Air)](http://www.pullmanturair.com/) offers weekly service (on Mondays) between Madrid and Punta Cana from about €200 each way.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for *local* flights (from an european country to an overseas territory of the same country) like Paris to Martinique or Guadeloupe because I thoguht this type of flight would be cheaper. As I was searching I found [XL Airways France](http://www.xl.com). They have a Paris <--> Punta Cana flight for around 500 euros.

Answer (score 1):

Norwegian just started flying to Puerto Rico (San Juan). It can be as cheap as 4,000 SEK

https://www.norwegian.com/uk/destinations/puerto-rico---san-juan